# Строка imap_body php

Tags: php, imap

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой код, которым вывожу письма с gmail

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
// логин
$email = "";
// пароль
$password = "";
// соединяемся с почтовым сервером, 
// в случае ошибки выведем ее на экран
$connect_imap = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", $email, $password) or die("Error:" . imap_last_error());
// проверим ящик на наличие новых писем
$mails = imap_search($connect_imap, 'ON "17-Jan-2020"');
// если есть новые письма
if($mails){
    // перебираем все письма
    foreach($mails as $num_mail){
        // получаем заголовок
        $header = imap_header($connect_imap, $num_mail);
        // достаем ящик отправителя письма
        $mail_from = $header->sender[0]->mailbox . "@" . $header->sender[0]->host;
        echo "От кого: ".iconv_mime_decode($mail_from,0,"UTF-8")." <br/>";
        // получаем тему письма
        $subject = $header->subject;
        echo "Тема письма: ".iconv_mime_decode($subject,0,"UTF-8")." <br/>";
        // получаем содержимое письма
        $text_mail = quoted_printable_decode(imap_body($connect_imap, $num_mail, FT_INTERNAL)); 
        echo "Тело письма: $text_mail <br/>";
        echo "<hr/>";
    }
}else{
    echo "Нет новых писем";
}
// закрываем соединение
imap_close($connect_imap);
?>
```

Но в данный момент в теле письма вначале присутствует данная строка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в конце так же такая строка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно убрать данные строки?

Comment: Можете предоставить какой-нибудь пример тело письма в виде текста, а не скрина

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов Тело письма: --b1_76e7438df532a9abe4ac1e461d9a5d0b Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8" Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Здравствуйте, Официальная! С уважением, Команда Facebook...